# How to keep light on while game is on running mode?

Tags: ios, iphone

I created one `cocos2d` game. iPhone light is off as per its setting.

**My question is** :- Is that possible to set iPhone light is keep on while my game is on running mode.

Or its by default take iPhone setting.

Comment: I don't want to play your game because it drain my battery too fast

Comment: By "light" do you mean keeping the screen on or the camera LED?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

This is not recommended as it will drain battery